# Can a sea quark swap places with a valence quark within a proton?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

I understand that a proton is composed of three valence quarks and a very large number of sea quarks that briefly come into existence and then annihilate as quark-antiquark pairs.

Is it possible for the antiquark to instead interact with and annihilate one of the valence quarks and for the remaining quark to replace the valence quark?

Comment: Yes. There is no way for us to keep track of which are sea quarks and which are valence quarks. The swapping happens all the time.

Comment: Although one should emphasize that the quark flavor is conserved - an up quark would not be replaced by a down quark (without any weak interaction taking place).